# Image align issue in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to align the two images, so that the bottom right of the first image, touches the top left of the second. I can't think of a good way to make this work info I also have to consider people have different browser sizes. Any suggestions?

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #F8F5F0;
}

.flexrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%
}

.flexcol {
  max-width: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flexrow">
    <div class="flexcol">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9sOCPL1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flexcol">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexrow">
    <div class="flexcol">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div class="flexcol"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/G55u0Uq.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have had a few issues here that are related to understanding how Flexbox work.

1. Using the `align-items` for vertically align the image container inside a `row` direction
2. Containing the `img` element to `100%` of the container's size (otherwise it renders at full size, which is not what you want)
3. Removing unneeded `display: flex` from child elements. You use `display: flex` on the parent element, and that gives `flex` properties to all its direct children.

This is the shortest explanation I can give. For more details, go over the [Flexbox documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) in depth.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #F8F5F0;
}

.flexrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%
}
.align-end {
  align-items: end;
}
.flexcol {
  max-width: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flexrow align-end">
    <div class="flexcol">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9sOCPL1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flexcol">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexrow">
    <div class="flexcol">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div class="flexcol"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/G55u0Uq.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @narxx - this is a bit closer to what I had in mind. And yes, still trying to learn all this flex stuff, was much easier when everything was tables.  

img {
  max-width: 117%;margin:-5px;
}
solves it for smaller windows, but not when you get above a certain size.

Comment: @MichaelNielsen I don't understand what's missing. The top-left image is always touching the bottom-right image, in all resolutions and sizes. What more do you need?

Comment: sorry, I am not the best at explaining things properly. If we are talking about the actually image then yes, they are touch just fine. But not visually, since some part of it are transparent and this makes it a lot harder.

Comment: StackOverflow is designed for asking general questions and learning how things work. Less about fixing your specific tasks. You can resolve your issue with changing the image, or playing around with CSS `translate`, but that won't be a generic answer, and it would only fit this very specific example.

Comment: thanks, just looking for a point in the right direction since I had no idea regarding a good solution for a problem like this. I could do a fix with different images, but then I wouldn't learn anything new. Css translate does actually seems promising, didn't even consider that one. Or maybe some Calc stuff, but that's above my skills at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the bottom right of the first image touches the top left of the second image. You can see this if you inspect element.

You just have to use a png image without background to achive this.

Try this example by changing the second image:

```
<div class="flexcol">
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/relaxed-brunette-woman-dressed-pajama-covered-with-soft-warm-duvet-has-deep-sleep-bedroom-poses-bed-mobile-phone-lies-near-has-some-time-before-alarm-clock-peaceful-nap_273609-45296.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Try the snippet in different resolutions. You'll notice that in some cases, the top image is kinda "stuck" to the top, while the text on the right side pushes the bottom image down, so the images don't actually touch...

Comment: @Narxx that could happen in the mobile, in this case you can use media query and do  `.flexrow {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}`in this case you will have an image and bellow somme texte and after the texte the second image

Comment: Don't enter the answer as comment. Edit your answer if you wish to include this part in.  Also, use snippets so it's a lot more readable and runnable

Comment: @Maryam, you are completely right if we talk image size., but I ment from a visual point of view. I can of course move it around with paddings/margins, but can't find a way to make it fit when I then resize the browser window.